# Font.Weight — regular is somehow thicker / bigger than medium?

Tags: swift, swiftui, fonts

I'm very confused by Font.Weight.

I created a test view to show all font weights, here is the result:

[image]

Why, then, when I use `.medium` and `.regular` in my project, is `.regular` thicker than `.medium`? See the code below and the resulting text in the image:

```swift
Text("Hello World!")
    .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
    .fontWeight(.medium)
    .foregroundColor(lightBodyText)
Text("Hello World!")
    .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
    .fontWeight(.regular)
    .foregroundColor(lightBodyText)
```

[image]

Comment: Really strange, it works correctly for me in the canvas but in the simulator it has the wrong weight

Comment: You don't need to use `design: .rounded` to work correctly

Comment: @sergio_veliz, not sure what you mean here. I need it as I want the rounded variant of the font. I can't use `.fontDesign(.rounded)`, as I'm targeting iOS 15+.

Comment: @Joseph your question is why? I answered it, I think it's bug on this line if you remove it, you can see correctly regular and medium thicker

Comment: @sergio_veliz, ok, but it doesn't really solve the problem. I've reported it to Apple, if it is indeed a bug when using rounded fonts.

Comment: @Joseph  also you can use size `.font(.system(size: 17, design: .rounded))` for correctly show if you really need rounded. Described font size you find [here][1]


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/typography/#sf-pro-rounded-and-sf-compact-rounded

Comment: @sergio_veliz, if I set a fixed font size like that, it won't change according with the user's accessibility font size. Also, I checked and it doesn't affect the issue in my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that each of the weights, except for regular, add an NSCTFontWeightTrait to the String. These values are used to adjust the weight from a "nominal" value of 0.

The weight are:
Black       0.62
Heavy       0.56
Bold        0.40
Semibold    0.29
Medium      0.23
Regular     none
Light       -0.40
Thin        -0.60
Ultralight  -0.80

Using a value of Regular removes the NSCTFontWeightTrait. In other word there is no instructions on how the system should change the nominal weight. Or said in a third way, "Hey system, show this in what ever the Apple UI guys thought would be a good default value."

For the default font, this is a little lighter than Medium.
For the rounded font, this is a little heaver than Medium.

Moral of the story, if you want control of the font weight set it to a value other than regular.

p.s. if you want to set these value for yourself, click on the [image] button in the debug window. Then click on the line of text in the vie and in the right panel it will show you the detail of the item in the view you clicked on.

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's interesting and totally counterintuitive for them to design it that way. Thanks for the explanation!